# 2 bit adder implementation

Tags: boolean-algebra

wanted to know the minimum number of gates required to implement a $2$-bit adder, with $4$ inputs $(A_0, B_0, A_1, B_1)$, and $3$ outputs $(S_0,S_1, Carryout)$ using ONLY Universal gates

Thank you.

Comment: "Only universal gates" isn't specific enough. `NOT` and `OR` together is a universal set. `NOR` by itself is universal. Exactly what set of gates would you like to use? Also, what have you tried? How many gates do you need for _your_ best attempt?

Comment: A few minutes of googling gives [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ovoQJDsPU0I/U-mnSZ2WG3I/AAAAAAAAAPY/vsK2exWgEKY/s1600/1111.jpg) diagram of a 4-bit full adder which only uses NAND gates. With a little work, this is easily reduced to your 2-bit half adder.